# AJAX always returning into Home Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

is there any body who can help me to solve my problem. 
i have 3 file `index.php` `process.js` `redirect_process.php`.
well, the `index.php` is my home page, and there is a form inside of it.
and the `process.js` is call everytime the `button submit` is clicked to validate the data of form, so, if there is an error inputted data, simply, do not return into true and show some error message, else return into true and then redirect into another page with `redirect_process.php`.
here is my code for `process.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_side').submit(function() { 
  var name_this = /^[a-zA-Z-' ]+$/;
  var return_process = false;
  if(name_this.test(document.getElementById("input_field_one").value) == false){
    alert('Error!');
    return_process = false;
  }else{
    $.ajax({ 
                type:"POST",
                url:"./r_p/redirect_process.php",//the link to call redirect process
                data: $("#my_form").serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                $("#my_form").trigger('reset');
    } });
                //No more validation here, so i want to go into another page now by returning into TRUE
                return_process = true; //This will be the cause now to go to another page.
  }
  return return_process;
 });
});
```

so lets say now there is no error inputted data, and i want now to redirect into another page using `redirect_process.php`. Here is my code for `redirect_process.php`:

```
...Some validation here
if (data is ok, and no error) {
    //Redirect into correct page
    header('Location: http://localhost/test/correct_page.php'); 
}else{
    //Redirect into wrong page
    header('Location: http://localhost/test/wrong_page.php');   
}
```

the problem is, it is always returning into `index.php` it is not redirecting in any link above.
please me help me. Thank you!

Comment: Probably you don't return `false` on your form. Always return `false` in your submit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sure everything will happen in your index.php  cause you call header inside a php file which you use it with ajax the header will work if you go to **redirect_process.php** directly 
(and always use **exit();** after **header();**)

do that  in php

```
...Some validation here
if (data is ok, and no error) {
    echo('OK');
}else{
    echo('Not OK');
}
```

then in submit event in js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_side').submit(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault;                              // use e.preventDefault;
  var name_this = /^[a-zA-Z-' ]+$/;
  var return_process = false;
  if(name_this.test(document.getElementById("input_field_one").value) == false){
    alert('Error!');
    return_process = false;
  }else{
    $.ajax({ 
                type:"POST",
                url:"./r_p/redirect_process.php",//the link to call redirect process
                data: $("#my_form").serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                $("#my_form").trigger('reset');
                if(response == 'OK'){
                 window.location.href= "http://localhost/test/correct_page.php";
                 }else{
                 window.location.href= "http://localhost/test/wrong_page.php";
                 }
    } });
                //No more validation here, so i want to go into another page now by returning into TRUE
                return_process = true; //This will be the cause now to go to another page.
  }
  return return_process;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_side').submit(function(event) { 
  var name_this = /^[a-zA-Z-' ]+$/;
  var return_process = false;
  if(name_this.test(document.getElementById("input_field_one").value) == false){
    alert('Error!');
    return_process = false;
  }else{
    $.ajax({ 
                type:"POST",
                url:"./r_p/redirect_process.php",//the link to call redirect process
                data: $("#my_form").serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                $("#my_form").trigger('reset');
    } });

  } 
      event.preventDefault(); //this line prevents the form from executing it's action, which is none and that triggers a reload.
  return false;
 });
});
```

You're a calling the onsubmit event via `jQuery.submit`. When parsed this event fires the forms action. Since there is none defined, because you use AJAX, this triggers a reload.

> event.preventDefault()

this prevents the event from firing the action.

```
 ...Some validation here
 if (data is ok, and no error) {
     //Redirect into correct page
     header('Location: http://localhost/test/correct_page.php'); 
    }else{
     //Redirect into wrong page
      header('Location: http://localhost/test/wrong_page.php');   
  }
```

The header line works, but not in your situation. It tells the browser to load a page a response. This response is loaded into the AJAX response and not redirecting the current page. Use [@Mohamed-Yousef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3385827/mohamed-yousef) answer as guide for that.